# How to count variable values django

Tags: python, django

I'm making my first django app, and trying count variables value

There is my current code, but at this moment it only return "valu1value2"

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def ohjelma1(request):
    value1= request.GET.get('value1')
    value2= request.GET.get('valu2')
    result = value1 + value2
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

Comment: `result = int(value1) + int(value2); return HttpResponse(str(result))`

Comment: That's because `value1` and `value2` in `request.GET` are two strings `value1` and `value2`, so if you add 2 strings up you got `value1value2` isn't it?

Comment: result = int(value1) + int(value2); return HttpResponse(str(result)) -> This worked! thaks so much! spent few hours trying figure that out and got answer there under minute :D